# Do we need to create a template in DocuSign to generate a document through code?

Tags: .net, docusignapi

I have a form in my web application(.Net 4.6 , MVC, c#). When user will submit the form i am planning to generate a PDF file and send this PDF file to DocuSign for user signature.

I went through the code in 
[DocuSignAPIOverview-EmbeddedSigning](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#quick-embedded-signing)

It seems i need a template to be created in DocuSign which will be equivalent to my form.

I don't want to go this route because i have some 20+ input fields. If i create a template in DocuSign i have to pass all these 20+ fields every time when a user request signature.

Please Advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating envelopes using a template is an optimal method as you are not required to pass the PDF bytes every time.

From [Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/templates)

> Templates are perfect for almost any DocuSign workflow that you do over and over again. They help streamline the sending process when you frequently send the same or similar documents, or send different documents to the same group of people.

However you can also create envelopes without using a template. You will have to pass PDF bytes everytime.

See sample code using the [c# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client)

[CoreRecipe.cs](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/Recipes/CoreRecipes.cs)

Answer (score 1):

Templates are extremely useful for Senders using the DocuSign web app since without a template, the Sender (a human) needs to repeat what they've done previously.

But your software app has no trouble repeating itself over and over for each envelope (signing request) that it wants to send.

And there is no technical reason to use templates from a software app.

One benefit of using a template, as @CodingDawg mentions is that a template can hold the documents, so you don't need to upload the docs each time.

A more important reason is that your app's administrators can create/update a template in DocuSign using the web app, that your app then sends out.

But this isn't necessary--your app's administrators can also set the characteristics of the envelopes that your app sends out via configuration settings in your app itself.

Because software apps have no trouble repeating themselves, it is common for apps to just generate the envelopes fresh each time.